# Firestore how to prevent creating new collections?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

We know how to write secure rules to limit actions on a collection, but, how to deny creations of new collections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow only writing to specific collections in your security rules is a two-step process

1. Fist [disallow writing to any documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/insecure-rules#closed_access) at the top-level.
2. Then selectively allow writing documents in the collections you want to allow.

For example (allowing access to a `users` collection only):

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```